# Get new password from OraOLEDB Password Change Dialog

Tags: c#, oracle12c

My C# client app using Oracle12c.

Password change dialog is opening when calling,

```
objOleDbConnection.Open();
```

Because the Password Expired(user must change next login) option was enabled when creating the database user.
Entering old password & new password makes the connection successful.

But I want to get the newly entered password from Change Password Dialog and store it for future purpose.

[image]

Password change dialog,

[image]